# Showing $K_G (X \times EG) =K(X \times_G EG)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, equivariant-maps

I know that $K_G (X \times EG) =K(X \times_G EG)$. I've seen the proof that this is the case for the vector space definition of K-theory, but I wanted one that works for the definition where $K_G(X)= [X, F(H)]_G$ for $H$ a $G$-universe (infinite sum of all irreducible reps) and $F(H)$ the fredholm operators on $H$. It seems to me that the easiest way to show this is to use sections, ie:
$$ [X \times EG, F(H)]_G = \Gamma [ (X \times EG)\times_G F(H) \to X \times_G EG ]  $$
then to somehow trivialize the $(X \times EG)\times_G F(H) \to X \times_G EG$ bundle.

I know $F(H) \times_G EG \to F(H) \times_{U(H)} EG \tilde{\to} F(H)$, where $U(H)$ is the unitary transformations on $H$, this is contractible by Kuiper's theorem and thus itself a model for EU and since $H$ is faithful then it is also a model for $EG$. So the first map is modding out by the action of $U$, the second is the isomorphism induced by evaluation. Maybe this is helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two maps are:
$$ \alpha: (X \times EG) \times_G F(H) \to X \times_EG EG \times F(H) $$
$$ \alpha([x,e,f] = [x,e],e^{-1}f $$
and 
$$ \beta: X \times_G EG \times F \to (X \times EG) \times_G F(H) $$
$$ \beta([x,e],f)=[x,e,ef] $$
Easy to check that they work.